# ABS doesn't work in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database which contains some dates alarms:

```
id          timealarm                        status
1           2014-10-23 13:30:00 +0000         1 
2           2014-10-23 13:29:00 +0000         1
```

All I'm trying to do, is to send the current date to the sql and perform the abs so that take the value (date) nearest the current date:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY ABS('2014-10-23 13:27:09 +0000' - timealarm) LIMIT 1
```

in this case this syntax returns me the **id 1**, instead of **id 2**, Why and how to solve this problem?

```
EDIT
```

> The field timealarm is a VARCHAR

Comment: To be clear: you are trying to take the absolute value of the difference between two strings?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get the value more nearest to the real date

Comment: My real date is 2014-10-23 13:27:09 +0000, the date more nearest inside database is the data with id = 2, but my code get the date id = 1, why?

Comment: But your *code* is computing the absolute value of the difference between two strings.

Comment: Hum strange... so how to do a good syntax for this?

Comment: can you change `timealarm` type to dates types ? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Yes I can, and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to subtract strings from each other, the database converts them into numbers.
So you end up subtracting 2014 from 2014, which results in the same value for all rows.

To be able to compute differnce, convert the date strings into some number (this requires dropping the time zone information, which is not understood by SQLite's [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)):

```
...
ORDER BY abs(julianday('2014-10-23 13:27:09') - julianday(substr(timealarm, 1, 19)))
...
```

Comment: sorry but this code doesn't work, my field timealarm is a varchar field... I need to change to date time?

Comment: There is [no date/time data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Strings work just fine, if you use a supported format.

Comment: Your code works, but to this, I change the syntax to: ORDER BY abs(julianday(substr('%@', 1, 19)) - julianday(substr(timealarm, 1, 19)))  ,and change my field to varchar, thanks